# what is the meaning of "the ideal $m$ of all polynomial in $A$ with zero constant term is maximal"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have some  confusion regarding Atiyah's Commutative algebra book, page number $4$.

> It is written that  the ideal $m$ of all polynomials in $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$  with zero constant term is maximal.

My thinking: Suppose, for $n=2$  we have  $m=(f,g)=(x^2+x,x^3+x^2)$

But here $f=x^2 +x$ and $g=x^3+x^2$ are reducible. This leads to a contradiction that $m$ is maximal.

My question: what is the meaning of the "ideal $m$ of all polynomials in $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with zero constant term is maximal"?

Comment: The ideal in your example does not contain **all polynomials** with $0$ constant term. For example, it does not contain $x$.

Comment: ok @AnuragA what is the meaning of polynomials with $0$ constant term?

Comment: So if $f(x) \in k[x]$, then $f(0)=0$.

Comment: But $ f(x)=x^2 + x \implies f(0)=0$ @AnuragA

Comment: That is true. But $m=\{p(x) \in k[x]\, | \,  p(0)=0\}$ includes **every** polynomial with that property. In your example, the ideal $m$ does not have every polynomial with that property.

Comment: The ideal $\mathfrak m $ of all polynomials in $k[x]$ with zero constant term is given by $\mathfrak m=\{\,f\in k[x]\mid f(0)=0\,\}$. In other words, $\mathfrak m$ is the kernel of $k[x]\to k$, $f\mapsto f(x)$ (and thereby it is clear that it is maximal)

Comment: It's like somebody says "The set of all prime numbers is infinite". And you're saying "My thinking: $\{2,3,5\}$ is a set of prime numbers, but it's finite! Contradiction!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of $m$ is not large enough as it does not contain all polynomials with constant terms equal to zero. The constant term of a polynomial is the coefficient not associated to any $x$ (or rather, associated to $x^0$).

To see this is a maximal ideal, consider the ring homomorphism $\phi : k[x] \to k$ given by $\phi (p) = p(0)$. Then this is a surjective ring homomorphism whose kernel is $m$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem $k[x] / m \cong k$, so that $m$ is indeed maximal.